# Given holidays and leaves how to maximize days in vacations?

Tags: algorithm

This is more of an algorithm review :-

Problem : Given the holidays as list of integers, between 0-364, and number of leaves N available, how to maximize the number of days in X vacations, where a vacation is a date range, which encompasses holidays that falls in the range and uses leaves for the rest in the range.

I believe the following pseudo code using getMaxVacations(X, 0, 364, N) might work with some small fixes & optimizations, but I am looking for other approaches to visualize the problem, not necessarily faster.

```
available_leaves (N) = 5
holidays = [7, 14, 20, 21, 35, 36]

getMaxVacation (X, start, end, N) {
  if X = 0 return 0;
  for (d : end to start + 1) {
    for (leave : N to 1)
      total = bestSingleVacation(start, d, leave) + getMaxVacation(X-1, d, end, N-leave);
    if max < total
    max = total
  return max
}

bestSingleVacation(start, end, leaves_to_use) {
  maxVacationSize = leaves_to_use
  for (i : start; i < end-maxVacationSize; i++) {
    for (j : i ; j < leaves_to_use) {
      if (!holidays.contains(j)) j++; // use the leave
    }
    if (maxVacationSize < j-i) maxVacationSize = j-i;
  }
  return maxVacationSize;
}
```

Comment: We have here the future most widely used algorithm

Comment: Would also be interesting to incorporate leave that accumulates over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something in Haskell using federal holidays (January 1-20 are at the end of the list so the program will utilize the winter holidays in the construction of holiday sub-sequences). It will output from longest to shortest total vacation days for X vacations, utilizing N or less days of leave - many of these vacations are one day long (but days of leave may be available to augment them). If you are looking for the maximum shortest vacation in X vacations, it may need some tweaking. This is a filtered most-combination approach.

Method:

1. List all the sub-sequences of holidays.
2. Form all groups of X number of sub-sequences from 1.
3. Filter 2. such that the days-in-between (days of leave) do not exceed N and return them sorted by number of vacation days descending.

Sample output for N=15, X=4:

```
(17,[[1,15],[53],[150],[245]]) -17 days of vacation, 13 days of leave utilized
                                 for the first vacation 

(14,[[15,20],[53],[185],[359,1]]) -14 days of vacation, 10 days of leave utilized
                                   for the first and last vacation
```

Program code:

```
import Control.Monad(guard)
import Data.List(sortBy, nub, intersect, sort, inits, tails)

federalHolidays = [53,150,185,245,285,315,332,359,1,15,20]
n = 15 --days of leave
x = 4 --number of vacations

differences xs = 
  sum $ map (\x -> x - 1) . tail 
  $ zipWith (\a b -> if a > b then a-b else a + 364 - b) xs ([0] ++ init xs)

countDays vacation = if null (drop 1 vacation) 
                        then 1 
                        else if last vacation > head vacation 
                                then last vacation - head vacation
                                else last vacation + 365 - head vacation

maxVacations = 
  sortBy (\a b -> compare (fst b) (fst a)) 
  $ zip (map (\x -> sum (map countDays x)) potentialVacations) 
  $ filter (\y -> sum (map differences y) <= n) potentialVacations
 where potentialVacations = nub (map sort $ solve [])
       holidaySubsequences = 
         filter (not . null) . concatMap inits . tails $ federalHolidays
       solve result = 
         if length result == x
            then [result]
            else do
              h <- holidaySubsequences
              guard (
                differences h <= n 
                && notElem h result 
                && all null (map (intersect h) result))
              solve (h:result)
```

Comment: Haskell looks like black magic, I am clueless :) Are you guessing the best X vacations given an ordered set of leaves taken in X vacations, and then maximizing that across all possible permutations of dividing N leaves in X groups ?

Comment: @gvijay my apology for not detailing the method. I added more detail in the answer that I hope will clarify it.